# cacheCounter errors when foreign key is NULL

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following tables:

```
Users (
    id [PK]
    address_id [FK]
)

Addresses(
    id [PK]
    users_count
)
```

And the following model associations:

```
Addresses $haveMany Users
Users $belongsTo Addresses (cacheCounter => true)
```

The `address_id` [FK] on the Users table allows NULL values.

In the Users controller I have 3 functions (add, edit, delete), both add/edit use `$this->Model->save()` and the `cacheCounter` updates OK, even with a NULL value in the foreign_key (address_id).

But the delete function uses `$this->Model->delete` and I get the following error:

```
 UPDATE [addresses] SET [user_count] = 0 WHERE [id] IS N''
```

This is due to the foreign_key (address_id) having a NULL value.

Is there anything I can put into the cacheScope to stop this error from happening??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried putting anything in the cacheScope (as written in the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#counterscope))? If so, what have you tried and what error does it give?

Comment: Yeah, I have tried things like 'User.address_id IS NOT NULL' / 'User.address_id >' => 0 / 'User.address_id' => true. Nothing seems to work and the docs / google does not seem to show you...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

app/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php
Line 1963

I wrapped the updateAll function with:

if  (!empty($keys[$foreignKey]))  {

Works a treat.

Comment: how can you mark someone down on an answer that works, without posting a better example? This question has been on here for 2 weeks and I have tried the other possibilities, to no avail. I also have this posted as a fix on Git, which is being reviewed currently. Just because it is an unwritten rule, not to change Cake. Does not mean you can't, it is an open source framework after all.

Comment: Because editing the cake source is _not_ an answer ([I can't find any open PR related to counterCache](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pulls)). Indeed, it's perfectly fine to edit the Cake source in the act of providing a fix for a recognised error - I don't see this answer as qualifying. "It turns out it was an error and <link>there's a fix for it now applied to the project</link>" would be an appropriate answer.